# SwiftUI Unexpectedly NavigationLink pops automatically

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios14.5

I have a simple use case where a screen pushes another screen using the NavigationLink. There is a strange behaviour iOS 14.5 where the pushed screen is popped just after being pushed.

Code:

```
NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) { EmptyView()}
```

I manage to create a sample app where I reproduce it. I believe the cause is the presence of `@Environment(\.presentationMode)` that seem to re-create the view and it causes the pushed view to be popped.

The exact same code works fine in Xcode 12 / iOS 14.4

Comment: How are you initiating the push?

Comment: in SwiftUI you have to use NavigationLink for navigating view.

Comment: Sure, but how are you deciding/triggering the push?

Comment: NavigationLink method has isActive parameter, when it is true then NavigationLink will be triggered. initially it is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was stuck in this since last week. To fix, I simply added this to my view containing my existing `NavigationLink`s:

```
NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
    EmptyView()
}
```