# iOS 15 NavigationLink pop automatically if destination is created dynamically

Tags: swiftui, ios15

This is a problem on iOS 15 RC only. It works all good on iOS 14.

The problem is if my destination on NavigationLink is created dynamically, it pop automatically if i try push a view via NavigationLink. Here is a bit code snippet

```swift
 NavigationLink(
     destination: (createSettingNavigationLink(name: nameAndImage[0])),
     label: {
         CellButton(title: nameAndImage[0], image: nameAndImage[1])
     }

func createSettingNavigationLink(name: String) -> some View {
        if name == "shop.Settings" {
            return ShopSettings()
        }
        if name == "shop.Goods" {
            return ShopGoodsManagementPage()
        }
        if name == "shop.Order" {
            return ShopOrderPage()
        }
        if name == "Customer Service" {
            return ServiceListPage(isStore: true)
        }
        if name == "shop.Performance" {
            return PerformanceManagementPage()
        }
        if name == "shop.Earnings" {
            return CommissionSummaryPage()
        }
        if name == "shop.Increase_sales" {
            return BCWebView(urlStr: Constants.increaseSalesGuide)
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Increase Sales Guide"), displayMode: .inline)
                    .navigationBarHidden(false)
            )
        }
        return EmptyView()
    }

)
```

By the way, the approach mentioned here [SwiftUI Unexpectedly NavigationLink pops automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67686125/swiftui-unexpectedly-navigationlink-pops-automatically) does not help.

Comment: Just a tip - give `createSettingNavigationLink` a `some View` return type, use `switch name { ... }`, and then you can remove the `return`s and `AnyView`s.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a [mre]. What you have here won't compile for anyone else.

Comment: @LiangWang: Why AnyView? why not View? why so many if? why not Switch? or why not a dic even?

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the AnyView.  However, my key point is why my case does not work in iOS 15 (  can compile but just not behavior right)

Comment: I've made some test code similar to your snippet, but cannot replicate your 
issue (I can show the test code if interested). 
All works well on ios-15 RC, using Xcode 13-beta (not Xcode 13-RC). 
Maybe your issue has to do with some other code/context that is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution is to change the above function to struct view. I think it makes sense since the struct view seems to keep states while function is pure stateless.